# Firebase cloud function always timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I'm exploring the firebase cloud functions and I'm trying to send a notifications with an http request.

The problem is that even if I manage to send the notification, the request always goes timeout.

Here's my script

/functions/index.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.friendRequestNotification = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

    const senderId = req.query.senderId;
    const recipientId = req.query.recipientId;
    const getRecipientPromise = admin.database().ref(`/players/${recipientId}`).once('value');
    const getSenderPromise = admin.database().ref(`/players/${senderId}`).once('value');

    return Promise.all([getRecipientPromise, getSenderPromise]).then(results => {

        const recipient = results[0];
        const sender = results[1];

        const recipientToken = recipient.child("notificationsInfo/fcmToken").val();
        const notificationAuthorization = recipient.child("notificationsInfo/wantsToReceiveNotifications").val();
        const recipientBadge = recipient.child("notificationsInfo/badgeNumber").val();
        const senderUsername = sender.child("username").val();

        const payload = {
            notification: {
              title: `FriendRequest`,
              body: `You have a new friend request from ${senderUsername}!`,
              badge: (recipientBadge+1).toString()
            }
        };

        if (notificationAuthorization) {

            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(recipientToken, payload).then(response => {

            });

        }

        return admin.database().ref(`/players/${recipientId}/notificationsInfo/badgeNumber`).setValue(recipientBadge+1);

    });

});
```

Plus It seems that the badgeNumber in never updated, is that related to the timeout issue?

Comment: For others who might run across this thread, also keep in mind that HTTPS requests to third parties require that you have paid Firebase account; you can't send HTTP requests outside Google on a free account to prevent abuse.

Comment: Oh, I see, where did you found this information? What about the database trigger?

Comment: On the Firebase pricing page, footnote 3 says "The Spark plan only allows outbound network requests to Google owned services. On the Blaze plan, Cloud Functions provides a perpetual free tier." https://firebase.google.com/pricing/

Answer (score 25):

HTTP-triggered Cloud Functions work just like Express apps -- you have a response object (`res`) that you need to use to send something when the request is done. In this case, it looks like you could do something like:

```
return Promise.all([
  /* ... */
]).then(() => {
  res.status(200).send('ok');
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err.stack);
  res.status(500).send('error');
});
```

Comment: See more details in the Firebase doc : https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#terminate_http_functions

Answer (score 3):

@Michael Bleigh answer is perfectly fine for this question, let me add more in this for the future users.

As per firebase documentation:-

> Use these recommended approaches to manage the lifecycle of your
> functions:
>
> - Resolve functions that perform **asynchronous** processing (also known as
>   "background functions") by returning a [JavaScript promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).
> - Terminate **HTTP functions** with `res.redirect()`, `res.send()`, or `res.end()`. (The case in this question.)
> - Terminate a **synchronous** function with a `return;` statement.

**Note**
It's important to manage the lifecycle of a function to ensure that it resolves properly. By terminating functions correctly, you can avoid excessive charges from functions that run for too long or loop infinitely. Also, you can make sure that the Cloud Functions instance running your function does not shut down before your function successfully reaches its terminating condition or state.

- **You need a paid plan (Blaze, pay as you go) to access external APIs.**

You might see below warning in firebase functions log if the billing account is not configured.

> Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and
> quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these
> restrictions

Check [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) for more information.