# Firebase Node.js admin SDK timeouts when trying to access Realtime DB

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

Using the Node.js admin SDK with Firebase Functions I get a timeout whenever I try to access the Realtime Database. This occurs only when testing a function locally (`firebase serve --only functions,hosting`) and when the default app is initialized using the `functions.config().firebase`.

This is a new behavior that started just a couple a days ago. However, if I try to initialize the default app with the `serviceAccount.json` file everything works as expected.

I'm using `firebase-admin` version *4.2.1* and `firebase-functions` version *0.5.9*.

I wrote a straight forward `http triggered` function that fails due to timeout:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const db = admin.database();

exports.testDbConnection = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  return admin.database().ref().once('value')
  .then(function(snapshot) {
      res.json(snapshot);
  }).catch(function(error) {
      res.json(error);
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you try setting the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to point to your service account JSON file?

Comment: Yes this is what I did to solve the realtime db timeout. I was actually wondering if this a bug in the firebase admin/functions SDK that should be brought up.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57425373/820861).

Answer (score 0):

from the documentation

> Always end an HTTP function with send(), redirect(), or end(). Otherwise, your function might to continue to run and be forcibly terminated by the system

see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#terminate_http_functions

Comment: Thanks for the answer but `res.json()` is the same as res.send with the exception of sending the response as JSON an not text. I've consulted the documentation, and as stated, everything worked just fine until a couple of days ago, no changes were done to the code.

Answer (score 0):

This might depend on the `firebase-tools` version that you are using, but looks familiar to this [Github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/344)

The solution for it is to either upgrade to the latest version of the CLI or use the workaround solution:

1. Go to https://cloud.google.com/console/iam-admin/serviceaccounts
2. Click “Create service account”, give it a name (e.g. emulator), give it the Project>Owner role.Check “Furnish a new private key”, pick “JSON”.
3. Save the file somewhere on your computer
4. Run `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="absolute/path/to/file.json"`
5. Run `firebase serve --only functions`

Comment: Thanks for your help, this is indeed what I have done to work around that current bug